# Multi-biome superflat/skyblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have created a skyblock world by setting a superflat world to generate with only air. Problem is, it doesn't seem to have any biomes other than forest. I would very much like, however, to have it generate different biomes throughout the world. Of course being skyblock there would be no natural generation of anything, but it would permit me to freeze water into ice, grow coral, etc.

Is there any way to change the biome generation settings of an existing world? Failing that, is there any way to create an empty world with variable biomes when generating from scratch (in which case I could just copy my current island to such a world)?

Answer (score 1):

Superflat worlds always have just one biome.

Tools like [NBTExplorer](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) allow you to edit Minecraft save files, including biomes.

But in your case it would probably be easier to start with a default world and then remove all blocks. You could for example do it like this:

```
/setblock ~20 200 ~ repeating_command_block{auto:1,Command:"execute at @p run fill ~-5 0 ~-5 ~5 255 ~5 air"}
```

Then fly around, preferably with maximum Spectator mode speed, and avoid the place where the command block was placed. You will empty the world around you by doing that.

There are also ways to delete all blocks with NBTExplorer, but I don't know how to do that. It would probably also involve editing the heightmap of skylight.
There are also ways with command blocks to automatically expand the area of emptiness, but that's a more complex project and you would either have to have a way to limit it or you would create ever increasing lag.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to just use mods to create a new skyblock world. Then copy in your existing buildings.

I personally use carpet sky additions to generate a single-player-ready skyblock world. This wouldn't require much work to set up. It also allows you to generate the world with any seed.

- [Fabric](https://fabricmc.net/) + the API.
- [Carpet](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/carpet)
- [Carpet Sky Additions](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/carpet-sky-additions) (do not forget to select the world type + datapack when generating the world)

This creates a 'skyblock' world option when you create a new world, allowing you to choose the seed like with a normal world. The world generation will just remove (almost) every block. It is possible to play this without the data pack too if you just give/place some resources like lava.

Just copy your build parts into the newly generated -skyblock type- world (**make backups!!**).

[MCA-selector](https://github.com/Querz/mcaselector) is very easy to use for copying but it would overwrite the biomes too. Meaning that anything you copy will still be in the forest biome in the copied chunks, resulting in rough cutoffs between your newly generated biomes and the copied ones.

[Litmatica](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/litematica) might be better. As long as you are in creative mode you would be able to copy (not just create a schematic overlay) the entire structure without changing the biomes from how your skyblock world generates them. It would, however, require some more know-how to do so.